# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' in mysql code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error, whenever I want to insert something into the database
I have looked around stack, but the answers are so complicated.

the error is : 
Order Error: 
**Duplicate entry '936791155' for key 'PRIMARY'**

```
$orderID = rand();
$orderQuery = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, PersonID, ProductID, Quantity, Price, 
OrderDate)
VALUES(".$orderID.",".$customerID.",".$productID.",".$selectedQuantity.",".$totalPrice.",'".$today."'";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery)) 
{
    echo "Order has been Successfull!";
} else {
    echo "Order Error: ".$sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

HERE IS MY SET UP CODE FOR MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders (
OrderID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, -- Connects to table 'Customer' and ID
PersonID int(11) NOT NULL,  -- Connects to table 'Orders' and OrderUserID
ProductID int(11) NOT NULL,
Quantity int(11) NOT NULL,
Price int(11) NOT NULL,
OrderDate DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Customers(PersonID),
FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProductID)
);
```

EDIT . I think its a problem with $customerID

```
$customerID = rand();
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Customers (PersonID, FirstName, Address, Phone)
VALUES (".$customerID.",'".$userName."','".$address."','".$phone."')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery)) {
     echo "Member verified, in database";
} else{
    echo "Member Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to insert OrdrID if the column type is AUTO_INCREMENT.  I guess you can omit that field in your insert query.

Comment: This values already in Order table for primary key

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge a query string with parameter values.

Comment: When you try the answer did you truncate your table and reset all the auto ID's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderID` is an auto increment column, you don't have to set its value in the insert statement, use this instert instead:

```
$orderQuery = "INSERT INTO Orders (PersonID, ProductID, Quantity, Price, 
OrderDate)
VALUES(".$customerID.",".$productID.",".$selectedQuantity.",".$totalPrice.",'".$today."')";
```

Just get rid of the `".$orderID.",` from the insert.

I also recommend you to use sql parameters to pass the values to the query, and don't use string concatenation.

Comment: @NicholasWalters Do you got the same error? or what happened??

Comment: @NicholasWalters I see that there is a missing closing bracket in your query string (at the end of VALUES(......`here` )

Comment: @NicholasWalters Please show the full error you got, this is very strange.

Comment: Order Error: 
Duplicate entry '911115575' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @NicholasWalters Can you try a plain sql insert statement into the tables from mysql workbench or phpmy admin and not from php?? with fixed test values

Comment: I used a regular insert statement using mysql workbench, it works fine without php

Comment: @NicholasWalters Then you have a problem in your php code, the sql is fine.

Comment: @NicholasWalters - Try to echo the sql statement before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an answer for this but just let me show you how to use prepared statements this makes your SQL much secure.

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO Orders (PersonID, ProductID, Quantity, Price, OrderDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt -> bind_param("iiiss", $customerID, $productID, $selectedQuantity, $totalPrice, $today);

if($stmt -> execute()){
    echo "Order has been Successfull!";
}else {
    echo "Order Error: ".$sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```